# Is there any prime number $a$ satisfying $a=\frac{k_1-k_2}{k_1-bk_2}$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Is there $k_1, k_2, b$ positive integers, $\gcd(k_1,k_2)=1$, $k_1>k_2$, $b>1$ such that $$\frac{k_1-k_2}{k_1-bk_2}$$ is prime number?

Comment: What is fixed and what varies? are $k_1, k_2$ fixed? And is the question "$\forall k_1, k_2 \exists b$"? Or $\forall b \exists k_1, k_2$?

Comment: [There are...](https://pastebin.com/raw/sxEBq7zu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would $k_1=31, \ k_2= 3, b=9$ work?

$$
\frac{31-3}{31-9\cdot 3}=\frac{28}{4}=7.
$$

Comment: I find it surprising that the OP did not at least consider plugging in some values by himself

Comment: The original equations: $ab-1=k_1d$ and $a-1=k_2d$ Where $gcd(k_1,k_2)=1$ and $a$ is a prime number.